# Reduce size of power source

Tags: batteries, solenoid

I want to use a 9 V battery to unlock a 12 V latch. I am using 8 AA batteries now. The 9 V battery will unlatch, but is too weak to overcome any resistance, no snap!

Comment: And what about a 12V lead acid battery?

Comment: So what's your question? By 9 V battery do you mean a [PP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-volt_battery#/media/File:Vintage_9_Volt_Transistor_Radio_Batteries,_Made_In_Japan,_USA,_Great_Britain,_Taiwan_And_Hong_Kong_(34634957785).jpg)? They have much lower capacity than AA cells so I think you can forget that idea. Measure the resistance of the 12 V latch solenoid and we can work out the current you require and from that the type of battery you need. [Edit] the missing information into your question. Don't bury it in the comments.

Comment: A boost converter?

Comment: charge a capacitor through a series resistor ... the resistor will limit the inrush current ... when capacitor is charged, connect the capacitor to the latch to unlock it

Comment: What's keeping you from replacing the latch with a 9V one?

Answer (score 6):

Connect a 10,000 uF, 16 V electrolytic capacitor across the 9 V battery. Place a switch between the capacitor and the lock. The capacitor will keep the voltage nearly constant and deliver the power to power the latch. Later, the 9 V battery will recover and recharge the capacitor.

Answer (score 6):

Even better may be to get a low cost 9V to 12V->15V boost converter. Use that between the 9V battery and a large 10,000uF / 24V capacitor. Let that boost converter output charge the capacitor to at least the full specified operating voltage of the latch mechanism coil to get it's best snap action performance.

The greater initial voltage across the capacitor will permit the capacitor to hold the latch coil in the "open"/"unlatched" position long enough to open whatever the latch is holding shut for cases where the latch is not a toggle unlatched / toggle re-latched mechanism.